# Hibernate OneToOne lazy loading and cascading

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, cascade

Here's what I'm trying to do.

1. Create a parent with a OneToOne relation to a child
2. The parent has to fetch the children using lazy loading
3. If parent is removed, so is the child
4. If the child is removed, the parent should not be affected
5. The cascade update and delete has to be translated into DDL

**class Parent**

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Child getChild()
```

**class Child**

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
public Parent getParent()
```

I've got **point 1, 3, 4** fully working and **Point 5** partially working, still need to solve how to translate the update part indo DDL.

**Point 2** is the big issue here, with my current solution the parent does not load the child lazily. The child however does load the parent lazily, but inverting the annotations would mess upp the cascading (**points 3, 4 and 5**).

I'm very confused right now, hoping I've missed something obvious, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Code requested by Adeel Ansari

'fetch=FetchType.LAZY' has been added to class Parent, otherwise the same as above.

```
IParentDAO parentDAO = DAOFactory.getFactory().getParentDAO();

parentDAO.beginTransaction();
//findByPrimaryKey uses 'org.hibernate.Session.get(Class clazz, Serializable id)'
parentDAO.findByPrimaryKey(1l);
parentDAO.commitTransaction();
```

The resulting hibernate queries, one fetching Parent and one fetching Child:

```
Hibernate: select parent0_.id as id0_0_ from parents parent0_ where parent0_.id=?
Hibernate: select child0_.id as id1_0_, child0_.parent_id as parent2_1_0_ from childs child0_ where child0_.parent_id=?
```

Here's the code for findByPrimaryKey:

```
public class HibernateParentDAO extends HibernateDAO<Parent, Long> implements IParentDAO {

    public HibernateParentDAO() {
        super(Parent.class);
    }
}

public abstract class HibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> implements IGenericDAO<T, ID> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public HibernateDAO(Class<T> c) {
        persistentClass = c;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T findByPrimaryKey(ID id) {
        return (T) HibernateUtil.getSession().get(persistentClass, id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've been having a similar issue. There are a few different solutions, but all of them are workarounds.

The short answer is: Hibernate does NOT support lazy one-to-one relationships.

The long answer (workaround) is:

1. Declare the relationship to be one-to-one on one side (child), and one-to-many on the other side (parent). Thus a `parent.getchild()` returns a set, yet it will be able to use lazy loading.
2. You can try to have the parent and the children to share the primary key, but this would require you to alter the schema.
3. You can try to configure a view in your database reflecting this one-to-one relationship.

Comment: tried workaround 1 and it does solve my problem, but using OneToMany <-> OneToOne does scare me a little bit... Do you know of any issues one might encounter using this workaround, besides the code being kinda ugly?

Comment: This is the workaround currently in use in my code. I have not yet encountered any issues, but you might want to add an extra method that does the following:
if( set has 0 resuls) return null object. else if (set has 1 result) return needed object.  else throw exception.

Comment: another addition to the workaround I'd recommend (haven't yet implemented this myself, but it's quite high in my TODO list) is to add a method getSingleObject ( return set.toArray()[0]; ) - but it's ugly. 
besides code ugliness, I have not yet encountered any issues with that.

Answer (score 11):

**[This part doesn't hold anymore]**

Modify this in your `Parent` like below,

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public Child getChild()
```

Should work.

---

**[Edited to explain why it will not work]**

> Right after loading B, you may call
>   getCee() to obtain C. But look,
>   getCee() is a method of YOUR class and
>   Hibernate has no control over it.
>   Hibernate does not know when someone
>   is going to call getCee(). That means
>   Hibernate must put an appropriate
>   value into "cee" property at the
>   moment it loads B from database.
>
> If proxy is enabled for C, Hibernate
>   can put a C-proxy object which is not
>   loaded yet, but will be loaded when
>   someone uses it. This gives lazy
>   loading for one-to-one.
>
> But now imagine your B object may or
>   may not have associated C
>   (constrained="false"). What should
>   getCee() return when specific B does
>   not have C? Null. But remember,
>   Hibernate must set correct value of
>   "cee" at the moment it set B (because
>   it does no know when someone will call
>   getCee()). Proxy does not help here
>   because proxy itself in already
>   non-null object.
>
> If your B->C mapping is
>   mandatory (constrained=true),
>   Hibernate will use proxy for C
>   resulting in lazy initialization. But
>   if you allow B without C, Hibernate
>   just HAS TO check presence of C at the
>   moment it loads B. But a SELECT to
>   check presence is just inefficient
>   because the same SELECT may not just
>   check presence, but load entire
>   object. So lazy loading goes away.

Reference: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Someexplanationsonlazyloadingone-to-one

---

**[Edited to include a workaround]**

You can use `optional=false` and `@LazyToOne` for the relationship that is not optional. Don't forget to include `cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE}`. Since, it is obvious for a not-optional relationship. Below is an example,

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="parent", optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE})
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
public Child getChild(){...}
```

This should work for you, as I can see you are using `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`, which means not-optional. Isn't it? But for optional relationship, you might like to consider workaround given by [iliaden, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293586/42769).

Comment: @Adeel Ansari, it does not seem to solve it, when I fetch a Parent from the DB the Child is still not LAZY fetched. After modifying Parent hibernate makes two queries, one fetching Parent and one fetching Child. Before modifying hibernate created one query that fetched both Parent and Child using a left outer join.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)`?
Also check [this](http://foursidetriangle.blogspot.com/2010/03/hibernate-lazy-onetoone-associations.html) blog and [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2388783) thread.

Comment: tried it, does not seem to change anything. Checking your links now.

Comment: Indeed, a possible solution for not-optional relationships. +1

Answer (score 0):

@One-to-one relationship **not support lazy initialization**.
To get object you **don't put FetchType.LAZY** in child class and obtain all child object.

```
class Parent

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
public Child getChild()

class Child

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
public Parent getParent()
```

Comment: If you don't put FetchType.LAZY, it'll just default to eager... no different than specifying eager.