# Lazy Initialization - Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

We have 4 Tables,

One A to One B 
One B to Many C
One C to Many D

All are configured Bi-directional and Lazy Fetch.

But if i try to fetch A, its fetching B also but not C and so. Is it a consistent behavior. How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is consistent behavior. Specification (JPA 2.0) is no too rigorous about expected result of using FetchType.LAZY:

> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider
>   runtime that the associated entity must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY
>   strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.

Above is taken from the definition of OneToOne, but same holds for other relationships, LAZY is hint, not normative.

Additionally Hibernate had decided not to implement lazy fetching of OneToOne relationship. If you need it, take a look to this: [Hibernate OneToOne lazy loading and cascading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290202/hibernate-onetoone-lazy-loading-and-cascading)